# Xamarain MVVMCross FragmentInfo Title

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I would like to change FragmentInfo title dynamytically and also like to add icon in tool bar could someone direct me to correct path

So when I enter name in below text box "Name" title of tool bar which is populated from FragmentInfo.Title changed to the name I entered also I would like to add icon above this "Name" tool bar and "Duration" text

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To change the title you can try something like this: 
`((MvxFragmentPagerAdapter)viewPager.Adapter).Fragments.ElementAt(1).Title = "Something";`

To set an icon on a tab you can use:

```
var tabLayout = view.FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.tabs);
tabLayout.GetTabAt(1).SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.your_icon);
```

Comment: Thanks Martin setting icon working 

For changing text from view model when I use this 

((MvxFragmentPagerAdapter)viewPager.Adapter).Fragments.ElementAt(0)

I don't get Title property at all it all happening in button click

Comment: You need to add a `using System.Linq;` when using ElementAt.

Comment: Thanks Martin I manage to change the info title which is changing but the text on tool bar still displaying same. I also tried to change the text of the tab layout getting NULL exception 

var tabLayout = container.FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.tabs);
                tabLayout.GetTabAt(0).SetText("Something");

Comment: Martin any more suggestions? about replacing text of tab to any value? Thanks